# Update the location of drawn shapes

Tags: c#, shapes

I have a collection of shapes.

> public List _shapes = new List();

Then what I want to do is adjust all shapes' location(x,y) inside of it when I scale the triangle. This is the first image:

[image]

And when I Adjust the triangle to max:

[image]

I want them to both have the same center point. How am I supposed to do that? here's how I scale for now.

```
if(rb_Both.Checked)
{
    tbox_Width.Text = scaledSize.ToString();
    //Updates both width and height, x-axis and y-axis while scaling
    triangleWidth = (float)(((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text)) * 96) / 25.4);
    triangleHeight = ((float)((triangleWidth * (Math.Sqrt(3))) / 2));
    tX = (s.center.X - (triangleWidth / 2f)) - 0.5f;
    tY = (s.center.Y + (triangleHeight / 3));
    trackBar_Size.Maximum = maximumValue;
}

//Adjusts the center of the triangle while it is scaled up
if (s.tPoints[2].Y <= 15)
{
    s.x = (s.center.X - (w / 2));
    s.y = (s.center.Y - (h / 2));
    s.center.Y = 250 + (((Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text)) - 110) * 2);
}
else if (Convert.ToInt32(tbox_Width.Text) <= 114)
   s.center.Y = 250;
break;
```

**Shape Class**

```
public Draw draw;
    public float width { get; set; }
    public float height { get; set; }
    public float x { get; set; }
    public float y { get; set; }
    public PointF center = new PointF(250f,250f);
    public PointF points { get; set; }
    public PointF[] tPoints { get; set; }
    public float triangleOffset { get; set; }
    public int strokeThickness { get; set; }
    public Color color { get; set; }
    public float userDefinedWidth { get; set; }
    public float userDefinedHeight { get; set; }
    public int userDefinedStroke { get; set; }
    public ShapeType type;
    public Status status;
    public enum ShapeType
    {
        rectangle, square, circle, ellipse, triangle, image
    }
    public enum Status
    {
        editing, start
    }
    //Methods
    public void DrawRectangle(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h, Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;
        this.type = ShapeType.rectangle;
        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)points.X, (int)points.Y, (int)w, (int)h);
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(c,stroke), points.X, points.Y,w,h);
    }
    public GraphicsPath RoundedRect(RectangleF Rect, float Radius)
    {
        GraphicsPath path2;
        if (Rect.Height >= Rect.Width)
        {
            Radius = (Rect.Height / 6f) * (Radius * 0.2f);
        }
        else
           {
            Radius = (Rect.Width / 6f) * (Radius * 0.2f);
        }
        float width = Radius * 2f;
        SizeF size = new SizeF(width, width);
        RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(Rect.Location, size);
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        if (Radius == 0f)
        {
        path.AddRectangle(Rect);
        path2 = path;
        }
        else
        {
            path.AddArc(rect, 180f, 90f);
            rect.X = Rect.Right - width;
            path.AddArc(rect, 270f, 90f);
            rect.Y = Rect.Bottom - width;
            path.AddArc(rect, 0f, 90f);
            rect.X = Rect.Left;
            path.AddArc(rect, 90f, 90f);
            path.CloseFigure();
            path2 = path;
        }
        return path2;
    }
    public void DrawSquare(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h, Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;
        this.type = ShapeType.square;
        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(c, stroke), points.X, points.Y, w, h);
    }
    public void DrawCircle(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h, Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;
        this.type = ShapeType.circle;
        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(c, stroke), points.X, points.Y, w, h);
    }
    public void DrawEllipse(Color c, int stroke, PointF points, float w, float h, Graphics g)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;
        this.type = ShapeType.ellipse;
        //Aliasing for smooth graphics when drawing and resizing
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(c, stroke), points.X, points.Y, w, h);

    }
    public void DrawTriangle(Color c, int stroke,PointF[] tpoints, float x, float y, float w, Graphics g)
    {
        tPoints = new PointF[3];
        this.width = w;
        this.strokeThickness = stroke;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.tPoints = tpoints;
        this.type = ShapeType.triangle;
        float angle = 0;
        tpoints[0].X = x;
        tpoints[0].Y = y;
        tpoints[1].X = (float)(x + w * Math.Cos(angle));
        tpoints[1].Y = (float)(y + w * Math.Sin(angle));
        tpoints[2].X = (float)(x+ w * Math.Cos(angle - Math.PI / 3));
        tpoints[2].Y = (float)(y + w * Math.Sin(angle - Math.PI / 3));
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
        g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(c, stroke), tPoints);
    }
```

**Draw Class**

```
    public Shape s;
    public List<Shape> _shapes = new List<Shape>();
    public Shape.ShapeType type;

    //Methods

    public void DrawAllShapes(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Shape shape in _shapes)
        {
            switch (shape.type)
            {
                case Shape.ShapeType.rectangle:
                    shape.DrawRectangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.square:
                    shape.DrawSquare(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.circle:
                    shape.DrawCircle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.ellipse:
                    shape.DrawEllipse(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.points, shape.width, shape.height, e.Graphics);
                    break;
                case Shape.ShapeType.triangle:
                    shape.DrawTriangle(shape.color, shape.strokeThickness, shape.tPoints.ToArray(), shape.x, shape.y, shape.width, e.Graphics);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no variable named `_shapes` in your code, so where are the shapes? `s` or `s.tPoints`?

Comment: wait that's from the Shape class, I'll put the shape class code in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by setting the Center variable in the Shape Class as **Static**.